# Jump to a specific view, which is already part of the storyboard, programatically

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, switch-statement, modalviewcontroller

I'm trying to switch to a specific ViewController, which is part of the storyboard, but the app keeps on crashing. And I want the transition to have a "modal" style.

Note that the view that I want to switch to does not have .xib file

This is the code that I'm using:

```
NSString * storyboardName = @"MainStoryboard";
NSString * viewControllerID = @"GalleryViewController";
UIStoryboard * storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle:nil];
GalleryViewController * controller = (GalleryViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:viewControllerID];
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: What is the error to the crash.. that would tell us what is wrong at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with segue.

First, in your storyboard, "control + drag" from the presenting view controller (the "self" in your code) to your destination controller (your GalleryViewController). This segue is not associated with any subview or widget.

Second, in the attribute inspector, give it a name "ToGalleryVCSegue", and set the type to "Modal".

Last, in the code, simply do:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"ToGalleryVCSegue" sender: self];
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Tkx !

Answer (score 0):

Go to your storyboard and select your view controller. On the right select the 3rd tab. Under Storyboard Id write GalleryViewController.